# Allowing all privileges to a user on PhpMyAdmin?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

I've been trying to grant all privileges to a user in PhpMyAdmin, because whenever I try to post to my host it says "Connection refused" and I'm thinking that's why. Does anyone know how to do this?

(I'm using Apache on Ubuntu 14.04)

Comment: Did you start Apache server before using it? `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart` ?

Comment: Try disabling firewall and selinux and see if it connects